# d3 Heatmap - zoom into selected area

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, heatmap

Right now I recalculate all the points which I select on the heatmap.  I am relatively new at D3 and don't particularly understand how the zoom behavior works.  Can someone help? This is the chunk of code that allows me to zoom into the heatmap with self selected Area:

```
function selectArea(area,svg,dataset,num,oldxStart,oldyStart) { 
        svg
            .attr("width",width)
            .attr("height",height)

        var cols = dataset.dim[1]; //x
        var rows = dataset.dim[0]; //y
        var zoomDat = [];
        var newxLab=[];
        var newyLab = [];
        //Makes the selection rectangles 
        area
            .on("mousedown", function() {
                var e = this,
                origin = d3.mouse(e),
                rect = svg
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("class", "zoom");

                origin[0] = Math.max(0, Math.min(width, origin[0]));
                origin[1] = Math.max(0, Math.min(height, origin[1]));
                d3.select('body')
                    .on("mousemove.zoomRect", function() {
                        var m = d3.mouse(e);
                        m[0] = Math.max(0, Math.min(width, m[0]));
                        m[1] = Math.max(0, Math.min(height, m[1]));
                        rect.attr("x", Math.min(origin[0], m[0]))
                            .attr("y", Math.min(origin[1], m[1]))
                            .attr("width", Math.abs(m[0] - origin[0]))
                            .attr("height", Math.abs(m[1] - origin[1]));
                    })
                    .on("mouseup.zoomRect", function() {
                            var m = d3.mouse(e);
                            m[0] = Math.max(0, Math.min(width, m[0]));
                            m[1] = Math.max(0, Math.min(height, m[1]));
                            //x,y Start/Finish for the selection of data => Can draw box the other way, and still work.
                            var xStart = Math.min(Math.floor(origin[0]/xScale(1)), Math.floor(m[0]/xScale(1)))
                            var xFinish = Math.max(Math.floor(m[0]/xScale(1)), Math.floor(origin[0]/xScale(1)))+1
                            var yStart = Math.min(Math.floor(origin[1]/yScale(1)), Math.floor(m[1]/yScale(1)))
                            var yFinish =Math.max(Math.floor(m[1]/yScale(1)), Math.floor(origin[1]/yScale(1)))+1

                            var newcolMeta = [];
                            var newrowMeta = [];
                            var newyDend = [];
                            var newxDend = [];

                            //If the Y dendrogram is selected, make the X dendrogram undefined 
                            //because I dont want the x dendrogram to change
                            if (num==1) {
                                xStart = 0;
                                xFinish = cols
                            //If the X dendrogram is selected, make the y dendrogram undefined 
                            //because I dont want the y dendrogram to change
                            } else if (num==2) {
                                yStart = 0;
                                yFinish = rows
                            }

                            //Get the data selected and send it back to heatmapgrid
                            for (i = xStart; i<xFinish; i++) {
                                newxLab.push(dataset.cols[i]);
                                if (data.cols!=null) { //If there is no column clustering
                                    newxDend.push(d3.select(".ends_X"+i).attr("id"))
                                }
                            }
                            for (i=yStart;i<yFinish; i++) {
                                newyLab.push(dataset.rows[i]);
                                if (data.rows !=null) { //If there is no row clustering
                                    newyDend.push(d3.select(".ends_Y"+i).attr("id"))
                                }
                                for (j=xStart; j<xFinish; j++) {
                                    zoomDat.push(dataset.data[i*cols+j]);
                                }
                            }

                            //Get the Metadata -> If there is more than one line of annotations, the data is in different places, just like the grid
                            if (colMeta !=null) {
                                for (i = 0; i<colHead.length; i++) {
                                    for (j = xStart; j<xFinish; j++) {
                                        newcolMeta.push(colMeta[i*cols+j])
                                    }
                                }
                                colMeta = newcolMeta
                            }
                            if (rowMeta != null) {
                                for (i =0; i<rowHead.length; i++) {
                                    for (j =yStart; j<yFinish; j++) {
                                        newrowMeta.push(rowMeta[i*rows+j])
                                    }
                                }
                                rowMeta = newrowMeta
                            } 

                            //Set new parameters based on selected data
                            dataset.dim[1] = newxLab.length;
                            dataset.dim[0] = newyLab.length;
                            dataset.rows = newyLab;
                            dataset.cols = newxLab;
                            dataset.data = zoomDat;
                            colAnnote.data = colMeta;
                            rowAnnote.data = rowMeta;
                            //Changes the margin, if the dimensions are small enough
                            if (dataset.dim[0] <=100) {
                                marginleft=100;
                            }
                            if (dataset.dim[1] <=300) {
                                margintop = 130;
                            }

                            xGlobal.range([0,width-marginleft])
                            yGlobal.range([0,height-margintop])
                            var x = xGlobal(1);
                            var y = yGlobal(1);

                            //This slows down the program (Remove())
                            d3.selectAll('.rootDend').remove();
                            oldxStart += xStart
                            oldyStart += yStart

                            //olsxStart + xStart because the dendrogram is translated
                            heatmapGrid(el.select('svg.colormap'),dataset,oldxStart,oldyStart);                            
                            //New Vertical dendrogram
                            dendrogram(el.select('svg.rowDend'), data.rows, false, 250, height-margintop,newyDend,oldyStart,y);
                            //New Horizontal dendrogram
                            dendrogram(el.select('svg.colDend'), data.cols, true, width-marginleft, 250,newxDend,oldxStart,x);
                            //New annotation bar, if no annotations, don't do this
                            drawAnnotate(el.select('svg.colAnnote'), colAnnote,false, width-marginleft,10);
                            drawAnnotate(el.select('svg.rowAnnote'),rowAnnote,true,10,height-margintop);
                            //zoomDat = [];
                            //remove blue select rectangle
                            rect.remove();
                    });
            });
```